# Ideapad 3 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS touchpad is too sensitive so my hand bumps it when typing

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

How can I reduce sensitivity of the touchpad?  It is way too big so when I type, the part of the palm that extends down from the thumb brushes the touchpad and I get all sorts of gestures I don't want like:
-highlight everything I am typing so far and delete

If anybody reading this has a choice between an Ideapad or Thinkpad, go for the Thinkpad.

Comment: It is a pain indeed and very frustrating. For some touchpads, one can change something, but not others: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/touchpad-pressure-debugging.html#touchpad-touch-size-hwdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `synclient` to access your touchpad settings, assuming that you have the Synaptic drivers installed.  Check out this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28306/looking-for-a-way-to-improve-synaptic-touchpad-palm-detection

Comment: Also, did you test? Does that work with libinput which is used nowaday? (answer: no).

Comment: So, as this does not work, where do we have the "right" answer then? So far the answer/tip I provided is the one most likely to come closest. As it is right now, I bet there is NO other option; feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: @vanadium Yes I did test... I used `synclient PalmMinWidth=7.5` and my palm doesn't trigger the trackpad as often.  How did it not work for you?

Comment: I found that answer after posting this and it seems to help, set `PalmMinWidth=10`

Comment: @Aaron Glad it works for you. You, and also  mLstudent33, must be using the traditional synaptics driver instead of libinput. For me, this command suggests installing the synaptics driver (`xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`).

Answer (score 0):

Tip: (i.e. Sensitivity 0)

Install and use
https://github.com/atareao/Touchpad-Indicator
... to disable the touchpad when you're not using it:

> Install from PPA
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install touchpad-indicator

Alternative: My Asus laptop has an option to turn it off in the Setup (BIOS), but that does not allow any use when set.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question: the question is how to tune the sensitivity. If that is not possible, then please state so.

Comment: I tend to disagree, widen your view please. One might see the question to be an instance of https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: The question is: control the sensitivity of your touchpad. Problem X is that the touchpad reacts too quickly. Turning it of, or not using the computer at all, of course will solve the problem.